# How to pass arrays when using Ellipsis in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

In my code I have a constructor with the signature

```
    public <T> Robot(Function<Robot, Integer> rom, double turnconstant, T... connections)
```

when I call the constructer with

```
Motor3[] ma1 = new Motor3[]{new Motor3(), new Motor3()};
robots[0] = new Robot(ROMS::hello, 5, ma1);
```

and print out the class name of each T typed `connections` inside the constructer with

```
for(T con : connections){
        System.out.println(con.getClass().getCanonicalName()+ " " + Motor3[].class.getCanonicalName());
```

I get

```
com.jacobhicks.Motor3 com.jacobhicks.Motor3[]
```

signifying that the `Motor3` array has is no longer and array in the `connections` array.

How can I keep store this as an array rather then as individual members?

Comment: Can you clarify the exact output from your `System.out.println()` statement? I feel like it should be `...Motor3 ...Motor3[]` (as there are two items printed).

Comment: What is `robots` or `ROMS`? Please show a [mcve]

Comment: I'm very confused. What output were you expecting?

Comment: What's the meaning of declaring a type variable on the constructor? Declaring a type variable on a constructor is pretty much never useful. The way you're using it (unbounded), you might as well use `Object... connections`.

Comment: You're printing out the type of each element _from_ the array, not the array itself.

Comment: @cricket_007 `ROMS` is irrelevant to the problem and `robots` is just an array containing Robot objects

Comment: @shmosel the output should be `com.jacobhicks.Motor3[] com.jacobhicks.Motor3[]`

Comment: Why? Is `con` an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your code is written and used, the type of `connections` is `Motor3[]`. In your loop, you are iterating through your `connections` array, so the individual elements (`con`) do not have the array type (`Motor3[]`), but rather the element type (`Motor3`). So your output is what I would expect and does *not* imply that `connections` is not an array.

Comment: Wouldn't connections be an array containing the values passed to the constructor? I expected connections to contain one array containing 2 Motor3's so `con` on the first run of the loop would be the Motor3 array passed in the beginning. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, `connections` is an array containing the values passed to the constructor. Yes, `connections` will be one array containing 2 x `Motor3`. No, in your `for` loop `con` will iterate through each element of your `connections` array, hence it will be a (different) `Motor3` each time.

Comment: No problem, happy to help.